# PowerBI: Change chart type upon selecting an element in Slicer

Tags: charts, powerbi, slicers

So I have this line chart in PowerBI which has Weeknumber as its X-axis. My Slicer also has Weeknumber as its Field (Element). When I select one single week from the slicer, the line chart turns to dots for obvious reasons. Is there any way in PowerBI for this line chart to be converted into bar chart in the same area when I select any element in my slicer.

This is what I have
[image]

[image]

This is what I want

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your table is named `ChartData` and has the values for the line are given by measures `[Line1]` and `[Line2]`.

Change your chart into a Line and Clustered Column Chart with `[Line1]` and `[Line2]` in the Line Values section and `ChartData[FiscalWeek]` in the shared axis section.

Define new measures which are blank unless a single week is selected:

```
Bar1 = IF(COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(ChartData[FiscalWeek])) = 1, [Line1], BLANK())
Bar2 = IF(COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(ChartData[FiscalWeek])) = 1, [Line2], BLANK())
```

Put those measures in the Column Values section and you should be good to go.

---

Note that this will still show the dots when you have the single week selected. If you don't want this, then define the line measures to only be non-blank when multiple weeks are selected and use those in place of `[Line1]` and `[Line2]`. E.g.

```
LineMeasure1 = IF(COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(ChartData[FiscalWeek])) > 1, [Line1], BLANK())
LineMeasure2 = IF(COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(ChartData[FiscalWeek])) > 1, [Line2], BLANK())
```

---

It should look like this with no week selected:

[image: Lines]

And like this when one week is selected:

[image: Bars]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried what you have written but it didnt work quite well.

1. Column values just takes one measure at a time. So that didnt quire work as you said(i.e. with 2). However I tried to work it with 1 measure.

2. When the bars are blank, the whole chart is blank. I wanted just the lines when nothing is selected.

Comment: @NeilS It definitely works for me. I'll post a couple screenshots in a minute. Is your Power BI up do date?

Comment: Also, I have joined tables. The line values are coming from Report tables, column Units and the Year and week from Calendar table. They are joined on Date. In the line chart I have axis as week, legend as year and values as units.

Comment: Yes. My PowerBI is working on Version: 2.52.4921.682 64-bit (November 2017)

Comment: @NeilS Don't use "Column series". Use "Column values". With your mention of Legend, I'm not sure you're using the same chart type.

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant column Values. I had Year in Column series thats why it was not allowing me to put more than 1 measure in column values.
I guess this should work.

Comment: any help with the following one [PowerBI question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47781009/powerbi-slicer-to-filter-a-table-only-when-more-than-1-value-is-selected)