# PowerBI: Slicer to filter a table Only when more than 1 value is selected

Tags: filter, powerbi, slicers

I have a table with 5 categories and units displayed into 2 types, Actual and budget.
[image]

I want to filter this table. Only when 2 or more values are selected in the slicer. Something like this.
[image]
[image]

I though of adding a measure, but dont know how to work the if statement exactly.

```
Measure = IF(COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(Report[Shipment Group])) = 1, "Something which would not filter the units", SELECTEDVALUE(Report[Units], SUM(Report[Units])))
```

Not sure if this is correct approach.Would like to know if any other approach is possible. Any help would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of an odd request, but I think I have something that works.

1. First, you need to create a separate table for your slicer values (or else you can't control filtering how you want). You can hit the new table button and define it as follows:

---

```
Groups = VALUES(Report[Shipment Group])
```

---

2. Set your slicer to use `Groups[Shipment Group]` instead of `Report[Shipment Group]`.
3. Define your new measure as follows:

---

```
Measure = IF(COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(Groups[Shipment Group])) = 1,
             SUM(Report[Units]),
             SUMX(FILTER(Report,
                         Report[Shipment Group] IN VALUES(Groups[Shipment Group])),
                  Report[Units]))
```

or equivalently

```
Measure = IF(COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(Groups[Shipment Group])) = 1,
             SUM(Report[Units]),
             CALCULATE(SUM(Report[Units]),
                       FILTER(Report,
                              Report[Shipment Group] IN VALUES(Groups[Shipment Group]))))
```

---

Note: Double check that Power BI has not automatically created a relationship between the `Groups` and `Report` tables. You don't want that.

Comment: Thank you for answering this. Yes this does work but unfortunately my slicer is tied up with other charts as well. So I need to use the Shipment group from Reports table.

Any other way around this?

Comment: @NeilS To get the behavior you want, I think it has to be a separate table. The only way around it I can think of at the moment would be to adjust the measure in the other charts. Wrapping it in an analogous `CALCULATE(...,FILTER(...))` might work.